# Finding the request's physical path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

In ASP.Net 5, how do I retrieve the physical path of a request if I'm creating ASP.Net middleware?

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var request = context.Request
```

Previously I would have either leveraged:

> HttpServerUtility.MapPath()

or

> System.Web.Request.PhysicalPath()

The new `Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Request` object only has a `Path` property, and I'm unclear how to convert the request path to the filesystem path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT April 2021**

My original answer used [IHostingEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-5.0%5D) which became obsolete from version 3.0. If you are using version 3.0 or later use [IWebHostEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-5.0) interface instead. Otherwise see the original answer below if you are using an older version.

Thanks @dan-jagnow for bringing this to my attention.

```
public class PhysicalPathMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    public PhysicalPathMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _next = next;
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var physicalFileInfo = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo(context.Request.Path);
        var physicalFilePath = physicalFileInfo.PhysicalPath;
    }
}
```

**Original Answer From 2015**

You can use IHostingEnvironment service as follows:

```
public class PhysicalPathMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    public PhysicalPathMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _next = next;
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var physicalFileInfo = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo(context.Request.Path);
        var physicalFilePath = physicalFileInfo.PhysicalPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: This advice should be updated to use [IWebHostEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-5.0) instead of [IHostingEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-5.0), which is obsolete.

Comment: @DanJagnow I updated my answer. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.